# How do I delete podcast episodes "Synced from iTunes" in iOS 13?

Tags: itunes, catalina, podcasts, podcasts.app, ios

I recently updated to Mac OS Catalina, so I no longer have iTunes. I've already tried deleting the Podcast App and re-installing, but there are still podcast episodes "Synced from iTunes."

Comment: This is missing some information. How does your iOs device relate to the Mac? Do you sync via Apple Music (or iTunes Match in the past) or do you sync over USB / WiFi or do you not sync anymore?

Comment: @bmike I sync my iPhone via USB / WiFi. Since I have Catalina, I currently use Podcasts on my mac to manage my subscriptions and the Finder to configure sync settings. The episodes I want to delete from my iPhone are not in my library on my Mac, but syncing my iPhone to my Mac doesn’t delete them. Also, the long press menu for podcast episodes does not show “Remove..” or “Remove Download.”

Comment: I have this same problem as well - the podcast on my phone has plus next to it, but there's no way I can find to delete it.  It's not on my mac, and I also sync via USB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the workaround I found - on your iPhone, launch Podcasts, select a program/show, go into **Synced from iTunes** and tap the **plus** button on each episode and then tap the **download** button.

Once the download completes for all the episodes, **Synced from iTunes** will disappear.

This workaround was based on an Apple Communities [post](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250744234) I saw.

I also have a [post](https://badcoffee.club/delete-synced-from-itunes-in-podcasts-on-iphone/) about this on my website if you are interested.

Comment: One more note: If you already have the episodes downloaded, delete them (swipe left) and then hold and select "Mark as played". This allows you to re-add them to the library as described in the answer.